# How to load a YAML 1.1 file without the YAML directive?

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Using `ruamel.yaml` v0.17.20, I'm trying to load files produced with PyYAML (or written by authors for software that only uses PyYAML). These files do not have a YAML directive, but PyYAML only supports YAML 1.1, so I need to somehow inform `ruamel.yaml` that it should load the file with 1.1, even though there isn't a directive.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)
yaml.load(Path("some/path/to/file.yml"))  # file.yml exists and does not have a YAML directive

print(yaml.version)  # prints None
assert yaml.version == (1, 1)  # this fails!
```

When I try to load a file without a YAML directive, the Parser overwrites my explicitly set `yaml.version` with `None` in `Parser.process_directives()`:

```py
    def process_directives(self):
        # ...
        yaml_version = None
        # code that loads directives (but there aren't any in my case)

        if self.loader is not None and hasattr(self.loader, 'tags'):
            self.loader.version = yaml_version
            # ...
```

https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/parser.py#l316

The load version matters for things like parsing octals and booleans.

How can I tell `ruamel.yaml` to use 1.1 when parsing a stream that is missing a YAML directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't indicate what happens when you load a YAML document
without `%YAML` directive, but you should check that:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = "- 042 # octal or not depending on YAML version"


print('# load as 1.1')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data[0])

print('# load as 1.2')  # the default no need to set the version
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data[0])
```

which gives:

```
# load as 1.1
34
# load as 1.2
42
```

You should be able to use `ruamel.yaml` (in round-trip) to load YAML 1.1 and dump as YAML 1.2.
You cannot use `ruamel.yaml` as a 1.2 to 1.1 convertor, nor is roundtripping 1.1 to 1.1
guaranteed to work for all files. Those are not the intended use of `ruamel.yaml`

In 0.17 the version information is not attached to the data loaded, but to the `YAML()` instance
that will change.

Alternatively to setting the version you can add an appropriate header to bytes/str before handing
it to `.load()`

FYI: The YAML 1.1 spec has been superseded 12 years ago and a PR for YAML 1.2 support in PyYAML
was made available in 2014. The recommended extension for files containing YAML documents
has been `.yaml` since 2006.

Comment: I'm roundtripping Ansible content, so, yes. I need to round trip 1.1 files.I need to do that at least until PyYAML supports 1.2 and Ansible starts using that newer version. I guess my biggest surprise was that it reset the version between load and dump.

Comment: I am not saying 1.1 can't be round-tripped, it is just not as well tested as YAML 1.2. in ruamel.yaml, just try it. Cross roundtriping (1.1 <> 1.2) is potentially more challenging, there might be some issues with floats as the definition for those changed a bit (and IIRC PyYAML did the wrong thing even for YAML 1.1).

Comment: Fair. ruamel.yaml's 1.1 round-tripping is about to get some wider testing, as `ansible-lint` 6.0.0 will support reformatting YAML files. Then in 7.0 (not sure on the version) it will modify YAML files between load and dump to upgrade between ansible versions or auto-fix common ansible-related issues. I would rather use YAML 1.2, but alas, PyYAML...